# Formatting SYSDATETIMEOFFSET in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm currently using `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` function in SQL Server and I want to format the output which is generated from the function is

```
2011-11-25 16:08:45.9281159 +05:30
```

I want to remove the extra nano seconds, for example I want the below output.

```
2011-11-25 16:08:45 +05:30
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS DATETIMEOFFSET(0))
```

You can define how accurate and precise your `DATETIMEOFFSET` should be - using a `0` as the precision gives you seconds - but no fractions of seconds.